# Clearcase: how to rollback all changes on specific branch?

Tags: clearcase

I made a bug fix on bug fix branch, but now I need to rollback all change on this branch. How to do that? I don't want to revert each file one by one, :(.

Comment: Have you labelled the branch prior to making your changes? If yes, you can merge that label to the latest version of your branch.

Comment: no, I didn't labelled it. Actually what I need is to revert a change set.

Comment: How many files are we talking about? You can merge each one with the previous version and use the older one as reference. It's a pain I know

Comment: hundred of files. That's why i am seeking help here, :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test it recently, but check out the perl script available with a ClearCase installation called **`cset.pl`** (also [available here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0927_bellagio/)):

```
ccperl cset.pl -undo myActivity
```

It should undo an activity by performing a negative merge (or substractive merge).
(That is, supposing you are using UCM since you are mentioning "changeset", which means "UCM activity")

Comment: this is resolved by a mate who wrote a perl script to revoke each file I touched. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sarstime: excellent. Any chance to see what that script looks like? (in a complementary answer below you would post, with said script content)

Comment: sorry, I don't know the detail. As I know, it's just a simple script. He wrote several statements to revoke my changes on that branch.