# Clearcase dependencies list

Tags: dependencies, clearcase

I am doing a deliver and am having trouble with dependencies on clearcase.

It shows that are dependencies found and in the list that shows are activities that are completed and have nothing related with the delivery.

Is there a way to skip this and make the deliver?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot skip those activities,  especially if they have been delivered ( to another stream themselves).

They are part of the stream timeline, and must be part of the deliver.

If they aren't too big, you could:

- deliver them first
- make a negative image of the deliver activity generated by that deliver: that will generate a new activity which cancels the modifications introduced by the first deliver.
  See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049738/6309
- deliver your activities.