# how to backup and remove an clearcase activity

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I need to remove the code changes of an activity from the child stream, which is shared among two projects. Wanted to remove code changes from Project A but I need to secure not to lose the changes in Project B

Can someone suggest me the possible solution and the next steps to be taken care to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Do a negative merge as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309: I'll put an answer in a few hours. You can apply that to an activity change set: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049738/6309

Comment: But activity is already delivered in project A....So we can not perform merge operation on delivered activities ....

Comment: It does not matter: you create a *new* activity which will contain a negative merge of the existnig activity change set.

Answer (score 0):

See "[Reverse Change set of an activity in Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8049738/6309)": you can use `ccperl cset.pl -undo`, or do for each file in an activity a [negative or subtractive merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309).

In both case, the goal is to create a new activity whose change set will represent the negative image of the existing activity.
You can then do what you want/need with it, like deliver it to another stream where the first activity was already delivered.