# Activity becomes undeliverable as folder in it was delivered. What could be the remedy?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are having 2 development stream and an integration stream in our project.

Following are the streams

```
      ProjName-Int-Stream
      Bangalore-Dev-Team
      Madurai-Dev-Team
```

Bangalore-Dev-Team member deleted a folder and created a new folder with the same name(Uncataloged the folder and created the same). Then he added more files into it and delivered it to integration stream.

Madurai team member was working in the same folder and unaware that Bangalore member deleted it. Now his activity is not listed while he is about to deliver his changes.

Has any one faced this scenario? If so what did you do as remedy action and how did you prevent it from happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are called **[evil twins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636909/6309)** (see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927206/cleartool-question/2927385#2927385): two elements -- here a directory -- created, that is "add to source control" *twice*, meaning they have different oid.

If the history of that directory isn't too important, the easiest way to go forward is for `Madurai` team to:

- rebase first
- accept the version of directory from `Bangalore` during  the rebase (his own file will disappear)
- redo its works on the files as newly created by `Bangalore`
- deliver

The other (cleaner) option would be for `Bengalore` to:

- restore removed directory "`D`" with its original content. The way you do that is by:

  - display the version tree of the *parent* directory of "D"
  - look for the previous version in that version tree which still referenced "D" in it (do some "`compare with another version`" between the current latest version of that parent directory and a previous version in the version tree)
  - right-click on that previous version (the one which stil references "D" and select "`merge to`", click to the current version (it will ask you to check out it)
  - select a graphical merge, and then, in the merge window, select the right version of the "D" (ie the one coming from the older version instead of the one re-created)
  - check-in the parent directory

If `Bangalore` did his modifications in a single activity, he could also [reverse that activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039121/clearcase-how-to-rollback-all-changes-on-specific-branch/6039686#6039686), which is simpler to do.
- do the modifications in the (now present again) directory "`D`"
- deliver again
- then `Madurai` rebases, and delivers too

Comment: Can you please paraphrase this statement? I am feeling little bit tough to understand compound sentence.(by listing the version tree of the parent directory of said removed directory "D", and merging the version in which the original "D" is referenced to the current version of that parent directory

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: I tried to detail the process to restore a deleted element

Comment: Thanks for your editing. Bangalore people delivered to integration stream and it is baselined. Is it still possible to reverse the activity?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Yes: the idea behind the "reverse activity" script is to generate *new* activities which would cancel what has been done. By delivering that new 'negative' activity, you would cancel what has been delivered on the stream.

Comment: Note to self: 5500th answer on SO