# branch merged dirX to main not showing on main view - cannot link either

Tags: clearcase

I add a dirX for a project on a branchX view.
Then by mistake I imported again on a main view.
It created two different dir elements and merges from branchX to main are not working.

I have:
On main view removed the dirX from parent. 
On branch view merged dirX from branchX to main. Which work in creating a main version of it

On branchX view I can see

```
ct desc parent/dirX@@main/LATEST
```

On main view the dirX doesn't show up. Neither I can

```
ct desc parent/dirX@@main/1 (ERR: no such file or dir)
```

I tried on main view to create link with same error:

```
ct co parent
ct ln /.../parent/dirX@@main/1 ./dirX (ERR: no such file or dir)
```

How can I put the main version of dirX that shows in the branch view appear in my main view ?

The branch view conf:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../branchX/LATEST
element * branchXLabel -mkbranch branchX
element * /main/0 -mkbranch branchX
```

main view conf:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

Thank you in advance,
-Jess

Answer (score 0):

You need to be:

- be in `main` view
- merger `branchX` to `main` view (through findmerge GUI for instance)

That will add `dirX` back to `main` view. No need to create links, especially to versions of `dirX` based on `/main` branch: those versions aren't the ones you want to see. They would be "**[evil twiws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636909/6309)**", as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9799649/6309).

Comment: I use clearmrgman and narrow it down to the parent to search for merges from branchX to a main view. It did not find them.

If I restored the rmname of partent@@/main/<prev_ver>/dirX then it works I get dirX back. However on a clear browser I get two diff elements of dirX whose for example:

main view: parent/dirX@@/main/1<br> does not match <br> branchX view: parent/dirX@@/main/1<br>

Comment: But you can do a version tree of `dirX` in `branchX` view, right? That is at least visible? If so, you can copy the full extended path of `dirX`. Note: `@@main` doesn't exist by the way: `@/main/...` does.

Comment: From branchX I can see the tree of dirX including the merged version on dirX@@/main/1
From main I can not see the dirX@@/main/1 element that appears in the branchX view.  I can see the old version of dirX@@/main/1 which is not the same as the one above.

I was wondering if there is a way to link using a uuid kind of id

Comment: @jessarah You should make sure you keep in `branchX` the original `dirX` directory. not one merged from `/main`. See [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4634373/6309) for restoring the right version. Then, and only then you can merge `branchX` to `/main`, and benefit from the same `dirX` in both branches.