# Reverting a users changes in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

We use ClearCase as control version system.

In our system sometimes we make releases without some developers commits because of time limit.

For example I made some changes in six classes but another user did changes in all or some of them also. And I have to commit code without his changes. So I scan my files with previous versions so that I can revert his changes. But it's a slow and boring process.

Is there another way to do that? Maybe an extension or a script?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to automate that process is through:

- [subtractive merge or negative merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309) (as described in this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21123001)):
  `cleartool merge -to filename -delete -ver \main\branch\version_number`
- `cset.pl`, which can take all the checkins of an UCM activity and cancel them.
  See "[Clearcase: how to rollback all changes on specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039121/clearcase-how-to-rollback-all-changes-on-specific-branch/6039686#6039686)".
  But this is for UCM (which might not be your case)

In both cases, the idea is to create a new version which cancels the version of your other developer.