# Clearcase - Rebasing to undo all check ins

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have stream where a lot of files have been changed and checked in. I want to rebase the stream to the recommended baselines, but I don't want any of my changes to remain. That is I want the files I modified to be rebased in such a way that there are identical to a new stream aligned to the recommended baselines.

Note: 
* I cannot delete the activity
* Manually modifying each file is too cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to create a new stream, which you can rebase to the right baseline.

But if that is not convenient, and if a rebase isn't possible (because ClearCase would deny to go back to an older baseline), then you would need to "revert" the previous activity which changed all those files.

See "[Reverting a users changes in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233946/6309)":
Usually, the script `cset.pl` used in "[Clearcase: how to rollback all changes on specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039686/6309)" can revert an activity.