# UCM ClearCase: undo deliver activity that is complete

Tags: clearcase

How can I rollback/undo a delivery activity that has been completed in Windows ClearCase 8.0.1?

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039121/clearcase-how-to-rollback-all-changes-on-specific-branch/6039686#6039686) but was not able to find `cset.pl` script any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The `cset.pl` 2005 script is still visible in this [web-archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080222214123/http://www.ibm.com:80/developerworks/rational/library/05/0927_bellagio/)

The script itself can be downloaded here: [`greenscar/scripts/clearcase/IBM_Rational_Tools_CSET_ICP/cset_icp.zip`](https://github.com/greenscar/scripts/blob/master/clearcase/IBM_Rational_Tools_CSET_ICP/cset_icp.zip), with [instructions on how to use it](https://github.com/greenscar/scripts/blob/master/clearcase/IBM_Rational_Tools_CSET_ICP/instructions.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The most important questions are:
Has the activity been included in a baseline?
Has this activity been delivered?

If either is the case, then you literally cannot delete the activity. In the baseline case, you can after purging the baseline. But delivered activities are irremovable.

If the fees have been changed in follow-on activities, you may want or need to do a subtractive merge to remove the changes before removing the activity.

Comment: The activity has not been included in the baseline. The deliver activity was completed.

Comment: The question is whether the subsequent deliveries have occurred. I assume that this is the case just opened with IBM today...